# how to identify the user in the windows 8 app?

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps

Can a user of a windows8 app have a userId?

I want to simplify the registration of the application. I don't want to have to enter a password, just to provide a username and the user ID that started the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the 'Enterprise Authentication' capability set in the application's manifest.
Then it's a matter of simply using:

```
var dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(
await Windows.System.UserProfile.UserInformation.GetDomainNameAsync());
```

If you use the above test code (for ex. in your startup method or OnNavigatedTo or on a button click), ensure you add 'await' to your method's signature